# Web.py - Unicode :Decode("utf-8") gives error

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

```
def search(str):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='arda', password='1', database='worddb')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    sqlq = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM names WHERE name = '%s'" %str
    cursor.execute(sqlq)
    if cursor.fetchone()[0]:
        return str + " " + "name"
    else:
        return str + " " + "not name"
```

when I search `Ömür` it gives me the output = `Ã¶mÃ¼r`

1. I declared # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

2 - tried `str.decode("utf-8")`

3 - Also I created my database with utf -8

when I try str.decode it gives me ascii error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Why do you think you need to decode? It's *encode* that you should be calling.

Comment: `str` is already a Unicode string. You can't decode a Unicode despite the `.decode()` method being available.  How are you validating the output?

Comment: Thanks for replies but as me and you expect nothing is wrong with str let me show the problem in my answer and thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the database is already a Unicode. We must assume that Web.py encodes it to UTF-8 on response.

Therefore, you need to add a `Content-Type` header with the `charset` set to `utf-8` so the browser knows the encoding of the page.

E.g.

```
web.header('Content-Type','text/html; charset=utf-8', unique=True)
```

Full Example:

```
def search(str):
    web.header('Content-Type','text/html; charset=utf-8', unique=True) 
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='arda', password='1', database='worddb')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    sqlq = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM names WHERE name = '%s'" %str
    cursor.execute(sqlq)
    if cursor.fetchone()[0]:
        return str + " " + "name"
    else:
        return str + " " + "not name"
```